# Select Eclipse WorkingSet with String

Tags: java, string, eclipse, plugins, working-set

I am currently working on a Eclipse Plug-In (Java). The Plug-In is showing some files in a table, and when I double click the column, I want to select the Workingset which it is in. The method to get the Workingset is already finished (returns the Workingset as a String). I just need help to select the Workingset.

```
private void jumpToWorkset()
  {
    m_viewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event)
      {
        IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection();
        Object first = selection.getFirstElement();
        MyFileInformation b = (MyFileInformation) first;
        String ws=b.getWorkingSet();
        //Insert Code to select working set here
      }
    });
  }
```

[description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uwIl.png)
If you need any further information feel free to ask!

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. At one point you seem to want the working set containing a file (but a file can be in multiple working sets). At another point you seem to want to select the active working set - but select the working set where? There isn't one active working set, different views may have different working sets active.

Comment: I want to select the working set containing a file. Which working set should be selected is already implemented. Maybe the added picture can help you understand my question.

Comment: Select the working set where? There isn't just one active working set. The Project view may have a different working set to the Packages view for example.

Comment: It should be selected in the package explorer

Comment: Package explorer doesn't provide an API to set the working set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IWorkingSetManager` looks after working sets. Get this with:

```
IWorkingSetManager manager = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkingSetManager();
```

Individual workings sets are represented by `IWorkingSet` get that using:

```
IWorkingSet workingSet = manager.getWorkingSet("name");
```

The active workbench window working set can be set using the `IWorkbenchPage.setWorkingSets` method.

Individual views may have their own active working set. These don't usually provide an API to set the value.

Comment: and is there a way to open a file of a workingset? When i open a file from a working set, the working might be selected...

Comment: What do you mean by 'open a file of a working set'?

Comment: with `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkingSetManager().getWorkingSet("emi").getElements()` i get all elements of a specific workingSet. And if i open a file of this elements in Eclipse, the workingSet should also be selected

Comment: Package explorer does not provide any APIs to do anything like this.